# Laravel 9 Hash::check() always returns false using Fortify

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

Using tinker:

```
>>> $user = User::create(['name_first' => 'test', 'name_last' => 'last', 'password' => Hash::make('password'), 'email' => 'test3@test.com']);

=> App\Models\User {#4771
     name_first: "test",
     name_last: "last",
     password: "$2y$10$9Yjm2xf0PBWdvbw42q3i5.7xW8UoXyLtDHHFI8LTerRIV3R0efvbi",
     email: "test3@test.com",
     uuid: Ramsey\Uuid\Lazy\LazyUuidFromString {#4732
       uuid: "0ef8dfaf-1068-4349-a4fe-5f0f23a30e58",
     },
     updated_at: "2022-09-12 23:17:06",
     created_at: "2022-09-12 23:17:06",
     id: 105,
   }
```

This returns true as expected.

```
>>> Hash::check('password', $user->password);
=> true
```

I copy pasted this code in my FortifyServiceProvider.php: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#customizing-user-authentication

When trying to log in with the User I created using tinker using my frontend (Vue 3 SPA with Sanctum and Fortify), I keep getting the message `These credentials do not match our records.`. Why is that?

By the way, for viewing purposes, I commented `password` from the `$hidden` array in `User.php`

Comment: Try cross-checking if the *front-end authenticated user* has his/her password hashed in the database.

Comment: *this returns true as expected* and two lines after that it returned false. I understand this is probably a typo but it did amuse me

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa what do you mean exactly?  In this case the user cannot be authenticated, because I keep getting a 422 response saying that the credentials do not match.

Answer (score 2):

It returns correctly for me because I have a User model with no accessors or mutators.

I would guess that you have a mutator on the user model that hashes the password for you, so you only need to pass plaintext password into the create function.

At present you are possibly hashing the password twice.

Comment: I triple checked my User model and I'm not manipulating the password field in any way, nor do I have any other mutators. Tinker seems to be working now for some weird reason, but I still cannot authenticate using the frontend.

Comment: Turns out that I disabled the mutators AFTER running the user seeders. Thats why none of the accounts matched.

Answer (score 0):

Man, I feel so stupid. I'm using a fresh L9 application and copied bits of code from another (older) app. I also copied this bit of code in my User.php model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
        
    static::creating(function (User $user) {
        $user->uuid = str()->uuid();

        $user->password = Hash::make(str()->random(20));
    });
}
```

This is used because the app I'm working on lets the administrators create new users. This immediately notifies the user to set up a new password.

But I copied this BEFORE seeding all my test data, hence why `password` wouldn't work. But I only commented the boot method out, AFTER the seeding was done. That's why authentication seemed to work for new users created with Tinker and not the seeded users.